# R: Comparing the Time for Random Searches

Tags: r, loops, optimization, random, while-loop

I am using the R programming language.

I am trying to optimize the *Rastrign Function*  using both Random Search With Replacement and Random Search Without Replacement:

```
Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2)
{
  20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
}

x1 <- x2 <- seq(-5.12, 5.12, by = 0.1)
f <- outer(x1, x2, Rastrigin)
```

[image]

**Part 1 : Random Search With Replacement:**

To sample with replacement, I generated 100 points (I converted these points to integer format so that it's easier to see which points are duplicates for **Part 2**), and then evaluated the function at these 100 points. I then extracted the row of data corresponding to the smallest value of the function. I also recorded the time taken:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

x1 = as.integer(rnorm(100,5,5))
x2 = as.integer(rnorm(100,5,5))
func_value = 20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))

frame = data.frame(x1,x2,func_value)

sort_frame <- frame[order(func_value),]

final_answer = sort_frame[1,]

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time

time.taken

Time difference of 0.01810408 secs
```

**Part 2: Random Search Without Replacement:**

Since I do not know how to write the code for the traditional way to do Random Search Without Replacement (i.e. generate random value, see if this generated value has already occurred : if not then evaluate function at this value, else generate new value until a unseen value is generated) -  since I want to evaluate the function at 100 values, I decided to generate 200 values in hopes that at least 100 values in these 200 values will be unique. Then, I repeated the above procedure:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

x1 = as.integer(rnorm(200,5,5))
x2 = as.integer(rnorm(200,5,5))

frame = data.frame(x1,x2)
de_duplicated = frame[!(duplicated(frame) | duplicated(frame, fromLast = TRUE)), ]

#check to make sure at least 100 values in "de_duplicated"

ifelse(nrow(de_duplicated)<100, "BAD", "GOOD")

[1] "GOOD"

#only keep 100 values in de_duplicated:

de_duplicated = de_duplicated[1:100,]

func_value = 20 + de_duplicated$x1^2 + de_duplicated$x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*de_duplicated$x1) + cos(2*pi*de_duplicated$x2))

final_frame = data.frame(de_duplicated$x1,de_duplicated$x2,func_value)

sort_frame <- final_frame[order(func_value),]

final_answer = sort_frame[1,]

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time

time.taken

Time difference of 0.03689885 secs
```

**My Question:** Since I am interested in comparing the times for **Part 1** and **Part 2** - I don't think it is fair, since I have written the code for **Part 2** in a very "clumsy" way.

If you were to write the code for **Part 2** in a more "traditional" way, i.e. with "while loops" - would this reduce the time required for **Part 2**? C**an someone please show me how to do this - is writing Random Search Without Replacement (i.e. **Part 2**) using "while loops" in fact the traditional way to do this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are example ways I might sample the function at integer values with and without replacement:

```
set.seed(123)

fSearchReplace <- function() {
  # sampling with replacement
  x1 <- as.integer(rnorm(100, 5, 5))
  x2 <- as.integer(rnorm(100, 5, 5))
  func_value <- 20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
  idxMin <- which.min(func_value)
  frame <- data.frame(x1 = x1[idxMin], x2 = x2[idxMin], func_value = func_value[idxMin])
}

fSearchNoReplace1 <- function() {
  # sampling without replacement by rejection
  frame <- unique.data.frame(data.frame(x1 = as.integer(rnorm(200, 5, 5)), x2 = as.integer(rnorm(200, 5, 5))))
  
  while (nrow(frame) < 100L) {
    sz <- (100L - nrow(frame))*2L
    frame <- unique.data.frame(rbind(frame, data.frame(x1 = as.integer(rnorm(sz,5,5)), x2 = as.integer(rnorm(sz, 5, 5)))))
  }
  
  func_value <- 20 + frame[1:100,]$x1^2 + frame[1:100,]$x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*frame[1:100,]$x1) + cos(2*pi*frame[1:100,]$x2))
  idxMin <- which.min(func_value)
  frame <- data.frame(x1 = frame$x1[idxMin], x2 = frame$x2[idxMin], func_value = func_value[idxMin])
}

fSearchNoReplace2 <- function() {
  # sampling without replacement using weights
  p <- diff(pnorm(-15.5:5.5, 5, 5))
  w1 <- c(p, rev(head(p, -1)))
  frame <- setNames(expand.grid(rep(list(-15:25), 2))[sample(1681, 100, prob = outer(w1, w1)),], c("x1", "x2"))
  frame$func_value <- 20 + frame$x1^2 + frame$x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*frame$x1) + cos(2*pi*frame$x2))
  frame <- frame[which.min(frame$func_value),]
}

print(fSearchReplace(), row.names = FALSE)
#>  x1 x2 func_value
#>   0  0          0
print(fSearchNoReplace1(), row.names = FALSE)
#>  x1 x2 func_value
#>   1  0          1
print(fSearchNoReplace2(), row.names = FALSE)
#>  x1 x2 func_value
#>   0  0          0

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fSearchReplace(), fSearchNoReplace1(), fSearchNoReplace2())
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                 expr   min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>     fSearchReplace() 220.7 255.65  298.925  291.60  324.40  490.8   100
#>  fSearchNoReplace1() 802.0 880.55 1043.916 1027.65 1132.70 2036.8   100
#>  fSearchNoReplace2() 495.7 530.85  650.703  610.35  679.65 2779.4   100
```

Note: if the search is *not* constrained to integers, `rnorm` can be treated as sampling without replacement. The probability of getting two identical pairs of `x1` and `x2` out of 100 is practically 0 (which is why `rnorm` has no `replace` argument).

Answer (score 1):

You would not use while loops for sampling without replacement.
Either use `sample`, which has an argument `replace`.
Or use some form of random ordering of a specified vector:

```
x <- 1:10
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

x[order(runif(length(x)))]
## [1]  6  8  2  5  3  7  1 10  9  4
```